# JavaScript Fibonacci function to HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, fibonacci

So I wanted to start making a script based on a course and I can't figure out why my output is only (0,1) in my fibonacci series function.

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n){
  var output = [];

  if(n === 1) {
    output = [0];
  }
  else if (n === 2) {
    output = [0, 1];  
    document.getElementsById("nr").innerHTML = output;
  }
  else {
    output = [0, 1];
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      output.push(output[output.length - 2] + output[output.length - 1]);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
    }
  }
  return output;
}


function calcButton() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = fibonacciGenerator();
}
```

```html
<input id="nr" name="nr" type="number" style="margin: auto; display: flex;">
  <button style="margin: auto; display: flex;" onclick="calcButton()">Calc</button>
  <div style="margin: auto; display: flex;" id="result"></div>
```

Tried different ways but I can't figure it out.

Comment: One problem, possibly obvious but missed is that your fib function takes a parameter, you provide none `fibonacciGenerator(n)`. You apparently decided not to pass a parameter to it in your calcButton() for some reason.

Comment: what do you mean by that? i tried this and the result is the same

Comment: i said that its based on a course and i wanted to modify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @GetSet means is that your function is called without `n`

Just feed it the input's value;

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n){
  var output = [];

  if(n === 1) {
    output = [0];
  }
  else if (n === 2) {
    output = [0, 1];  
    document.getElementsById("nr").innerHTML = output;
  }
  else {
    output = [0, 1];
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      output.push(output[output.length - 2] + output[output.length - 1]);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
    }
  }
  return output;
}


function calcButton() {
  let number = document.querySelector('input').value // Get the input's value
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = fibonacciGenerator(number); // and feed it to your function
}
```

```html
<input id="nr" name="nr" type="number" style="margin: auto; display: flex;">
  <button style="margin: auto; display: flex;" onclick="calcButton()">Calc</button>
  <div style="margin: auto; display: flex;" id="result"></div>
```

Comment: well, now i see what i missed, the input value on my calc, that's what he meant, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is due to the input not being read from the text field. Problem can be resolved by using '`var n = document.getElementById("nr").value`' to read input

**Here is the working code with the function updated to read input from the text field:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <h2>Fibonacci series</h2>
    <input id="nr" name="nr" type="number">
    <button onclick="fibonacciGenerator()">Calc</button>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script>
    function fibonacciGenerator(){
      var n = document.getElementById("nr").value
      
      var output = [];

      if(n === 1) {
          output = [0];
      } else if (n === 2) {
          output = [0, 1];  
          document.getElementsById("nr").innerHTML = output;
      } else {
          output = [0, 1];
          for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
              output.push(output[output.length - 2] + output[output.length - 1]);
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
          }
      }
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = output
    }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]